# Trying to create a RegEx for the following patterns

Tags: regex, pcre

Here are the patterns:

```
Red,Green (and so on...)
Red (+5.00),Green (+6.00) (and so on...)
Red (+5.00,+10.00),Green (+6.00,+20.00) (and so on...)
Red (+5.00),Green  (and so on...)
```

Each attribute ("Red,"Green") can have 0, 1, or 2 modifiers (shown as "+5.00,+10.00", etc.).

I need to capture each of the attributes and their modifiers as a single string (i.e. "Red (+5.00,+10.00)", "Green (+6.00,+20.00)".

Help?

Comment: I think that it would be best if you supplied a couple of concrete examples. Despite the fact that the 'and so on' helps us understand the problem, having some concrete examples can help us generate and test the actual regex.

Comment: A language tag would be good too since regex comes in different flavors.

Comment: This is for a shopping cart, where attributes can be created for products. Red and Green are examples, but the user can enter in anything for the attribute name (Small, Medium, Large, X-Large, etc.) and the 2 modifiers stand for: additional price, and additional weight, in that order.

Comment: Here is another example to show some variations that I need to account for: foo (+15.00,-10.00),bar (-10.00,+25),baz,bing,bam (150.00,-5000.00). The words "foo","bar", etc. are user entered values, so the "Red" and "Green" were just examples, and weren't meant literally as the only options. Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for the help thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example (PCRE):

```
((?:Red|Green)(?:\s\((?:\+\d+\.\d+,?)+\))?)
```

Explanation:

```
(...)              //  a capture group
  (?:...)          // a non-capturing group
    Read|Green     // matches Red or Green
  (?:...)?         // an optional non-capturing group
    \s             // matches any whitespace character
    \(             // matches a literal (
    (?:...)+       // a non-capturing group that can occur one or more times
      \+           // matches a literal +
      \d+          // matches one or more digits
      \.           // matches a literal .
      \d+          // matches one or more digits
      ,?           // matches an optional comma
    \)             //matches a literal )
```

**Update:**
Or actually if you just want to extract the data, then

```
((?:Red|Green)(?:\s\([^)]+\))?)
```

would be sufficient.

**Update 2:** As pointed out in your comment, <strike>this would match anything in the first part but `,` and `(`:</strike>

```
([^,(]+(?:\s\([^)]+\))?)
```

*(does not work, too permissive)*

to be more restrictive (allowing only characters and numbers, you can just use `\w`:

```
(\w+(?:\s\([^)]+\))?)
```

**Update 3**:

I see, the first of my alternatives does not work correctly, but `\w` works:

```
$pattern = "#\w+(?:\s\([^)]+\))?#";
$str = "foo (+15.00,-10.00),bar (-10.00,+25),baz,bing,bam (150.00,-5000.00)";

$matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo (+15.00,-10.00)
            [1] => bar (-10.00,+25)
            [2] => baz
            [3] => bing
            [4] => bam (150.00,-5000.00)
        )

)
```

**Update 4:**

Ok, I got *something* working, please check whether it always works:

```
(?=[^-+,.]+)[^(),]+(?:\s?\((?:[-+\d.]+,?)+\))?
```

With:

```
$pattern = "#(?=[^-+,.]+)[^(),]+(?:\s?\((?:[-+\d.]+,?)+\))?#";
$str = "5 lb. (+15.00,-10.00),bar (-10.00,+25),baz,bing,bam (150.00,-5000.00)";
```

`preg_match_all` gives me

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5 lb. (+15.00,-10.00)
            [1] => bar (-10.00,+25)
            [2] => baz
            [3] => bing
            [4] => bam (150.00,-5000.00)
        )

)
```

Maybe there is a simpler regex, I'm not an expert...

Comment: This is close. I probably should have provided more info. "Red" and "Green" are example "variations" entered by the user, but "Red" and "Green" can be anything. Here is an example: foo (+15.00,-10.00),bar (-10.00,+25),baz,bing,bam (150.00,-5000.00)

Comment: @Travis: Then it depends what kinds of characters you allow. The most generous would be to replace `(?:Red|Green)` by `[^,(]+`.

Comment: Now we're getting there. I'm using the following pattern: /([^\(\),]+(?:\s\([^)]+\))?)/ within PHP's preg_match_all() (http://us3.php.net/preg_match_all). I'd like to capture my example in the comment above as follows: array(0 => "foo (+15.00,-10.00)", 1 => "bar (-10.00,+25)", 2 => "baz", 3 => "bing", 4 => "bam (150.00,-5000.00"). It is currently capturing it as: array(0 => "foo", 1 => "+15.00", 2 => "-10.00", 3 => bar , 4 => "-10.00", 5 => "+25", 6 => "baz", 7 => "bing", 8 => "bam", 9 => "+150.00", 10 => "-5000.00")

Comment: We're so close. I'm playing around with things on my end, but I do need to allow more flexibility than what "\w" gives me. I like the solution of using [^\\(\\),]+ but I can't seem to get it to capture correctly. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Felix The output you have there is perfect, but I need to allow for other characters than what "\w" allows. I need to allow for basically anything EXCEPT "(", ")", and ",". Take the following for example: 5 lbs. (+10.00,+5.00),10 lbs. (+20.00,+10.00)

Answer (score 0):

PCRE format:

```
(Red|Green)(\s\((?P<val1>.+?)(,){0,1}(?P<val2>.+?){0,1}\)){0,1}
```

Match from PHP:

```
preg_match_all("/(Red|Green)(\s\((?P<val1>.+?)(,){0,1}(?P<val2>.+?){0,1}\)){0,1}/ims", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Yes! '?' means '{0,1}'. I wrote that format because it's easy to know. Thanks.^^

Comment: Mmmh ok, I think the regex looks more complicated with that but that is only my opinion

Comment: Sorry. I'm not focused in simple format, just wanna give a way to let it done. And I'm not good at English. If I have tough sentence, please forgive me. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bid:

```
/
  (?:^|,)                   # Match line beginning or a comma
  (?:                       # parent wrapper to catch multiple "color (+#.##)" patterns
    (                         # grouping pattern for picking off matches
      (?:(?:Red|Green),?)+      # match the color prefix
      \s\(                      # space then parenthesis
      (?:                       # wrapper for repeated number groups
        (?:\x2B\d+\.\d+)          # pattern for the +#.##
      ,?)+                      # end wrapper
      \)                        # closing parenthesis
    )+                        # end matching pattern
  )+                        # end parent wrapper
/
```

Which translates to:

```
/(?:^|,)(?:((?:(?:Red|Green),?)+\s\((?:(?:\x2B\d+\.\d+),?)+\))+)+/
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, it was only catching the last pattern before. This will catch all matches (or should).